# How to dynamically inject providers in NestJs

Tags: node.js, dependency-injection, nestjs, metaprogramming

My team is trying to identify a way to dynamically DI such that there can a bulk insertion point without a need to spell out + import each Module.

```
@Module({
  ...
  providers: [
    WorkerService,
    WorkerResolver,
    Worker2Service,
    Worker2Resolver........
  ]
})
```

want to achieve

```
var allModules = ... // logic here to include all my resolvers, or all my services

@Module({
  ...
  providers: [
    ...allModules
  ]
})
```

Comment: The only easy way I can think of to register each **provider** is reading all the files that exports the provider (leveraging the _convention over configuration_ model) you want to register

Comment: @MicaelLevi Yea, that's where we are stuck at, the DI happens at compile-time and if I try reading files, it would report that nothing existing in the dist/ directory.

Comment: I think you can circumvent this by using dynamic modules

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is correct, but instead of using `useValue`, try to use `useClass`:

```
export class WorkerCoreModule {

  static async forRootAsync(): Promise<DynamicModule> {
    // Feel free to change path if your structure is different
    const workersPath = glob.sync('src/**/workers/*.worker.ts');
    const workersRelativePathWithoutExt = modelsPath
      // Replace src, because you are probably running the code
      // from dist folder
      .map((path) => path.replace('src/', './../'))
      .map((path) => path.replace('.ts', ''));
    const workerProviders: Provider<any>[] = [];
    const importedModules = await Promise.all(
    workersRelativePathWithoutExt.map((path) => import(path)),
    );
    importedModules.forEach((modules) => {
      // Might be different if you are using default export instead
      const worker = modules[Object.keys(modules)[0]];
      workerProviders.push({
        provide: worker.name, 
        useClass: worker,
      });
    });

    return {
      module: WorkerCoreModule,
      providers: [...workerProviders],
      // You can omit exports if providers are meant to be used
      // only in this module
      exports: [...workerProviders],
     };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [glob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob) package to dynamically find modules then use NestJs dynamic module feature to load them dynamically.

Suppose all of your worker files are stored in a directory named `workers` and with extention `.worker.ts`:

```js
    @Module({})
    export class WorkerModule {
      static forRootAsync(): DynamicModule {
        return {
          module: WorkerModule ,
          imports: [WorkerCoreModule.forRootAsync()],
        };
      }
    }
```

```js
export class WorkerCoreModule {

  static async forRootAsync(): Promise<DynamicModule> {
    // Feel free to change path if your structure is different
    const workersPath = glob.sync('src/**/workers/*.worker.ts');
    const workersRelativePathWithoutExt = modelsPath
      // Replace src, because you are probably running the code
      // from dist folder
      .map((path) => path.replace('src/', './../'))
      .map((path) => path.replace('.ts', ''));
    const workerProviders: Provider<any>[] = [];
    const importedModules = await Promise.all(
      workersRelativePathWithoutExt.map((path) => import(path)),
    );
    importedModules.forEach((modules) => {
      // Might be different if you are using default export instead
      const worker = modules[Object.keys(modules)[0]];
      workerProviders.push({
        provide: worker.name, 
        useValue: worker,
      });
    });

    return {
      module: WorkerCoreModule,
      providers: [...workerProviders],
      // You can omit exports if providers are meant to be used
      // only in this module
      exports: [...workerProviders],
    };
  }
}
```

Now suppose you have a simple worker class with path `src/anyModule/workers/simple-worker.ts`, you can use it like this:

```js
class WrokersService {
  constructor(@Inject('SimpleWorker') simpleWroker: SimpleWorker) {}
  .
  .
  .
}
```

If you want to omit `@Inject('SimpleWorker')` and automatically inject modules like NestJs services then you need to make these changes to `WorkerCoreModule`:

```js
workerProviders.push({
  provide: worker,
});
```

However in order for this to work you need to be sure that your **workers** classes are decorated with `@injectable()`.

Comment: I think for this you still need to inject SimpleWorker into WorkerService. Also if I'm understanding your approahc correctly, it has to assume the files are all converted 1 to 1 from typescript to javscript. When in reality our app is bundled into one file. So the solution needs to occur at compile time.

Comment: Are you using Webpack? How does it end up in one file?

Comment: yes, we are compiling it into a main.js similar to client sided applications

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing. I bundle all my code using webpack into a single server.js file. When using glob 'src/**/workers/*.worker.ts' will not be a valid path. How did you overcome this?

Comment: @VladBlaj I think you need to use `.js`, because this will be run after compilation

Answer (score 0):

You can use those packages:

[nestjs-autoloader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nestjs-autoloader) for controllers scan

[nestjs-dynamic-providers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nestjs-dynamic-providers) for providers scan

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).